# Validate Tuxedo Service Authentication and Encryption

Tags: security, middleware, tuxedo

I am doing a risk review on online systems. These systems uses Tuxedo middleware to do some requests/ do services for the system. However, I am not a programmer or Tuxedo expert.

I want to know how to validate that tuxedo is actually enforcing encryption/authorization for the requested services from it (TUXEDO) is utilizing ATMI.

Answer (score 0):

In Tuxedo a service called AUTHSVC is responsible for authentication. You may ask the Tuxedo Admin to tell you how often the AUTHSVC was called. So at least you can verify that authentication is performed.